# WebStorm - Double tapping and then holding cmd on mac shows tool window bars

Tags: configuration, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

Does anyone know how to disable this? I have tried looking for it in 'find actions' and also searching for it in 'keymaps' both by name and by keypress.

Comment: AFAIK it's hardcoded and it's active only when `View | Appearance | Tool Window Bars` option is disabled.

Comment: Watch after https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-112097